# How to block google maps api v3 panning in the gray zone over north pole or under south pole?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using google maps v3 javascript API i cannot find a way to block the panning of the map over the north pole or under the south pole. 
As an example embedded maps on this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide
has the same behaviour, zooming out with the world view and panning north bring the view in a complete gray area.

How to prevent like it's done on official site http://maps.google.it ?

Comment: See [this explanation](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm) from [Mike Williams' Google Maps API v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/).  The Google Maps Javascript API v2 is deprecated (and turned off) but the same concept applies to v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working for me with the attribute "restriction":

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('#mapCanvas'), {
  zoom: 2,
  center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
  tilt: 0,
  restriction: {
    latLngBounds: {north: 85, south: -85, west: -180, east: 180},
    strictBounds: true
  },
});
```

Comment: tried this but it is panning horizontally while it's fine vertically

Comment: For some reason, in the same way `{ north: 90, south: -90 }` doesn't work vertically, `{ west: -180, east: 180 }` doesn't work horizontally. So `{ north: 85, south: -85, west: -175, east: 175 }` worked for me

Answer (score 15):

**UPDATE** - **The following answer doesn't look to work anymore, I suppose it's because google maps API has been upgrade. I leave the code here for reference.**

Thanks to geocodezip comments i modified Mike Williams' solution for my case.

Here is the [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aa3SH/)

Relevant code part:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    checkBounds(map);
});
// If the map position is out of range, move it back
function checkBounds(map) {

var latNorth = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
var latSouth = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
var newLat;

if(latNorth<85 && latSouth>-85)     /* in both side -> it's ok */
    return;
else {
    if(latNorth>85 && latSouth<-85)   /* out both side -> it's ok */
        return;
    else {
        if(latNorth>85)   
            newLat =  map.getCenter().lat() - (latNorth-85);   /* too north, centering */
        if(latSouth<-85) 
            newLat =  map.getCenter().lat() - (latSouth+85);   /* too south, centering */
    }   
}
if(newLat) {
    var newCenter= new google.maps.LatLng( newLat ,map.getCenter().lng() );
    map.setCenter(newCenter);
    }   
}
```

Comment: For whoever also wondered why 85, please see [latlongrid.gif](http://www.csgnetwork.com/latlongrid.gif). Poster was trying to constraint the viewport within the 85 degrees.

Comment: This doesn't work (tried the fiddle above). From the logging, my guess is that Google stopped passing the real value (eg, -100 etc) and instead passes modulus (or similar).

Comment: Also, this problem seems to happen in production; ie, big companies have the same issue (eg; foodora). However, [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com) doesn't have the poblem.