# How to make a google map not to leave world bounds?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wonder how to make a google map not to leave world bounds, like on google maps site itself.
I am using javascript google map api v3, here is my map options:

```
mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, 0),
  zoom: 3,
  minZoom: 3,
  zoomControl: true,
```

I've restricted map zoom, but user still can drag out of world bounds and even select region there.

[image: Snapshot]

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: You could check the map bounds while dragging, and set the center back to the last acceptable value when the bounds fall off your criteria.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27115480/1238965) btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a general check using some conditional statement like if...else and comparing if the current Lat/Lng is falling out of a specified boundary (which is a world bound in your case).

I would recommend you to look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901611/google-maps-api-v3-limit-map-bounds) that may provide you some leads of how to proceed.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23609552/2305243 for Google Map v3 API, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution I'd like to share:

```
if (!allowedBounds.intersects(map.getBounds())) {
        map.panToBounds(allowedBounds);
     }
```

it will return to the initial set bounds (minimum way) when the whole screen left the bounds.