# How to prevent panning outside world edges on google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I start by saying I have looked at plenty of SO answers, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580831/how-to-block-google-maps-api-v3-panning-in-the-gray-zone-over-north-pole-or-unde) is what gets closer.

So basically I did:

```
    var defaultLatLong = {
        lat: 45.4655171, 
        lng: 12.7700794
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: defaultLatLong,
      zoom: 3,
      minZoom: 3,
      restriction: {
        latLngBounds: {
          east: 180,
          north: 85,
          south: -85,
          west: -180
        },
        strictBounds: true
      }, ...
```

But that prevents top/bottom panning while it is still panning left/right.

Any idea why?

**UDPATE**

I tried the following:

```
    var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
         new google.maps.LatLng(85, 180), 
         new google.maps.LatLng(-85, -180)
    );
    var lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
        if (allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
          // still within valid bounds, so save the last valid position
          lastValidCenter = map.getCenter();
          return; 
        }
        // not valid anymore => return to last valid position
        map.panTo(lastValidCenter);
    });
```

But while it stops from panning horizontally, I cannot pan to the poles so top/bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapRestriction.latLngBounds):

> A restriction that can be applied to the Map. The map's viewport will not exceed these restrictions.

> **latLngBounds**
> **Type:**  LatLngBounds|LatLngBoundsLiteral
> When set, a user can only pan and zoom inside the given bounds. Bounds can restrict both longitude and latitude, or can restrict latitude only. **For latitude-only bounds use west and east longitudes of -180 and 180, respectively.** For example,
> latLngBounds: {north: northLat, south: southLat, west: -180, east: 180}

Set the longitude limits to something that isn't -180/+180.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/48xtkpo3/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var defaultLatLong = {
    lat: 45.4655171,
    lng: 12.7700794
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: defaultLatLong,
    zoom: 3,
    minZoom: 3,
    restriction: {
      latLngBounds: {
        east: 179.9999,
        north: 85,
        south: -85,
        west: -179.9999
      },
      strictBounds: true
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```